# HTTP Request in AsyncTask from cURL request

Tags: android, curl, android-asynctask, httprequest

I have built a web service that will receive an image as input and will respond with a JSON result .

**cURL Request:**

```
curl -X POST -F "file=@images/Sample1.jpg" http://192.168.0.101:5000/Img_Emotion/
```

**Output :**

```
{
    "angry": 0,
    "disgusted": 0,
    "fearful": 0,
    "happy": 99.97,
    "sad": 0,
    "surprised": 0,
    "neutral": 0.03
}
```

Now I am trying to build an android application that will use HTTP Request to get response from this API with `AsyncTask`.

So far I have done a similar thing for `GET` method without posting any data.

```
   @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            // This is getting the url from the string we passed in
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);

            // Create the urlConnection
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode ==  200) {
                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                String response = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                Log.e("result",response);
            } 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("error", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

I need to do it by posting an Image to the API from the camera or local storage and get back the response.

Comment: Have you dig google _upload image to server in android_ kind of this?

Comment: @Piyush Im not sure if uploading an image works for my API , since the request is just taking the image , converting it to data stream & passing it to the API , where it is directly processed instead of saving anywhere .

Comment: try this https://coderwall.com/p/zjuwbg/upload-files-and-data-to-server-from-android-app